# Is there a function in python similar to calling `initctl list`?

Tags: python, linux, unix, process

I need to get a list of all possible running processes(whether they are stopped currently or not) from the system, without keeping a record myself.

I was wondering if there is a better way to get a list of these processes in python without having to do the dreaded `subprocess` output parsing of an `initctl list` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` to get the running process names. You need to list the files in `/proc` and filter the numerical ones for getting access to list of the processes running on your system.

However I wouldn't call this accessing *"all possible running processes"* because that would include kernel threads as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I worded my question poorly. I wanted all processes that may have been running at one time, but might be stopped now, and the running ones.

Comment: Linux doesn't keep track of those afaik.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Python has standard facilities for that. There's the non-standard [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) package. Depending on what you're trying to do it may be easier to grovel around in the `/proc` filesystem than parse output from a command-line utility.